# Yosemite, ruby issues

Tags: ruby, osx-yosemite

I got a new Macbook Pro with Yosemite, I had Mavericks installed on my previous machine.  IT said that he reimaged from my old machine, but there were many things missing. I didn't think too much of it, being in a hurry I just started manually installing all my globals,  (node, npm, mongodb, sass)  along with other software I was missing.

**The Problem**
I can't seem to get anything ruby related to work.  I get the same error for all gem install attempts.

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:15:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems/util/stringio (LoadError)
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1204:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1204:in `<module:Gem>'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:115:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require'
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

Keep in mind I haven't touched ruby, I'm not even using homebrew since it's installed with ruby I get the same error when I try.

ruby -v gives me this:

```
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]
```

echo $PATH

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/ryanore/npm-global:/data/db:/usr/local/bin/mongodb/bin
```

There is a good chance that I'll need to completely reinstall Yosemite but I'm not a Ruby guy so I'd love someone to tell me this is an easy fix.

Please and thank you.

Comment: It's an easy fix.   Tell the IT guy that he obviously did not image the machine, as if he did you would have an identical setup, with the exception of available (probably) space on your hard drive.  Have him use the correct image.  Barring that, you are going to have to do some installations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny enough, the correct answer ended up being what @vgoff said in a comment.  Tell The IT guy that he did it wrong.

I was in the middle of a massive 4 month project and could not wipe my machine, until it was over. I could not solve the problem with rbenv or rvm because it always lead to the same error.  I couldn't even install them.

I appreciate all the answers but in the end, **this edge case could only be solved with a clean install**.

Answer (score 2):

You are currently using the OS X default Ruby installation. It also seems that some gem installations are missing.

I would recommend installing [RVM](https://rvm.io) and using the [Ruby Version Manager](https://rvm.io) to install your preferred Ruby version (I would go with 2.2)*.

This will allow you to both install the updated Ruby version and to keep the OS's Ruby installation intact.

After you install a clean Ruby updated version, just select the updated version using rvm (`rum use 2.2`)  and install all the gems you need - you might want to run `bundle install` from your app's folder, if you're using Bundler (which is Rail's default gem manager).

No need to reinstall the whole system for such a small matter, but having a clean updated Ruby installation is always fun.

P.S.

Make sure you install XCode and the command-line tools before you install any gems that need to be compiled. The ruby installation is likely to require XCode as well.

* make sure to follow [RVM's](https://rvm.io) instructions and to choose your newly installed Ruby version before installing any gems. You might want to make the newly installed Ruby version the default version for your user: `rvm use 2.2 --default`

Comment: Thanks, I'm leaning toward rbenv which is a whole other topic.  But I  appreciate the answer.

Comment: As an update,  RVM uses homebrew which requires ruby which ends up giving me the same error.  All roads lead to this error.  Thanks again man.

Answer (score 1):

Install Xcode and command-line tools. Install command-line tools by running in terminal

```
xcode-select --install
```

As for a *Ruby Version Manager*, I prefer rbenv. You're going to run into too many problems using system ruby.

**Install RBENV:**

Clone the repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
```

Add Rbenv to your $PATH - Run in Terminal:

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Add rbenv init to your shell - Run in Terminal:

```
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

RESTART YOUR TERMINAL FOR CHANGES

You should be able to Run:

```
 type rbenv
```

Which should output: "rbenv is a function"

Now install Ruby-build as a plugin

Clone the repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
```

There are also some recommended libraries you should install to avoid issues with dependencies - assuming you're using homebrew:

```
brew install openssl libyaml libffi
```

Now for installing Ruby:

To list available versions

```
rbenv install -l
```

To install a version

```
rbenv install 2.2.0
```

To set it globally run:

```
rbenv global 2.2.0
```

There are more commands available, but those should get you started.

https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv

https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build#readme